# Nuxt - Commit then submit

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using nuxt.js and have a button to submit a form that goes to a method. I need to put some data in the store before I submit my form however it's skipping straight over my commit and submitting the form.

What should I use in this case?

Commit the mesage and when the message is set submit the form. Do I need Fetch, Ascync or a promise?

**Form**

```html
<form ref="sfForm" action="http://blahblah/thank-you" method="post" @submit.prevent="sfFormSubmit('contactUs')">
```

**Method**

```js
methods: {
   sfFormSubmit(type){
      this.$store.commit('messages/setFormMessage', type);
      this.$refs.sfForm.submit();
   }
}
```

Comment: What you are describing is quite literally impossible. How are you verifying that the commit does not happen?

Comment: If I comment out the submit() the commit fills the store with the item passed, if I uncomment out the submit() it does not fill the store

Comment: What exactly does you commit do? Does your store persist data anywhere? Given you navigate away from this page when you submit the form, where exactly do you expect the store state to live?

Comment: Ok Thanks for that..I'm using nuxt-vuex-localstorage and I forgot to add my new store item to the localstorage array in nuxt.config.js and this now works